# How to use Itunes-like functionality of windows-7 with WPF? (thumbnail toolbar)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, thumbnail-toolbar

How to use such functionality of windows-7 with WPF (one that uses Itunes - see the Prt Scrn below)? [image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/wpff.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MSDN article describes this and other new features that devs can use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446%28classic%29.aspx#thumbnail

The feature is called the thumbnail toolbar.  Here is a tutorial which covers how to do this from WPF:
http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2009/08/31/developing-application-with-wpf-and-windows-7-part-ii/

Answer (score 0):

It might be in here.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack